# rails PaperClip / S3 / ImageMagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, imagemagick, paperclip

I'm using paperclip in my rails 3 app to upload photos, resize with ImageMagick and then post to S3.

For the life of me, I can't figure out why this process is soooo slow on my localhost? Even without any resizing it's crazy slow... 30+ seconds for one photo?

And my network & cpu aren't even working hard?

Why?

**Updating with Model:**

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :photo_album

  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable

  #Paperclip for photo
  has_attached_file :photo,
                    :styles => {:large => "600x600>"},
                    :default_style => :original,
                    :default_url => '/images/:attachment/default_:style.png',
                    :path => "/photos/:user_id/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                    :storage => :s3,
                    :s3_credentials => File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 's3.yml'),
                    :s3_protocol => 'http'
end
```

Comment: What is the file size of the picture(s) you are trying to upload?

Comment: anywhere from 28kb to 248kb (pngs,jpgs) I've tried several. The size of the file doesn't seem to be a variable. how long should this take on a local machine?

Comment: I'm doing S3 uploads with paper clip on localhost at this moment, the longest is about 3 seconds

Comment: I'm on a Mac, and I've experienced similar times when uploading to S3 via Paperclip. Have you deployed to somewhere like Heroku and tried it on there? Mine was wicked fast when going thru Heroku.

Comment: I do not know answer to this question, but in my experience I have realized that work with imagemagick is not meant to me done in real time. So what I do is create delayed_jobs every time I have something to upload. Hey at least is scale-able :)